# How create GA report for list of URLs

Tags: google-analytics

Noob question here... I would like to create a report or be able to view pageviews and unique pageviews for a list of about 10-15 URLs on my web site. I would like to be able to see the data broken out for each URL. The pages do not share a common URL structure. Here's an example of a few:

- www.example.com/ppc-ase-1/
- www.example.com/cotf-thank-you/
- www.example.com/rt-sis-1/

Can anyone point me to how to do this in GA?

Thanks for any help you can offer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it as a custom report. You will have to list all your urls in the filter, but once it's saved, you only have to do that once.

The other option is to do it as a segment, again, you will have to list all the urls, but only once, then use that segment whenever you want to see a report on those pages.

Comment: Thanks Goodwood. Your answer pointed me in the right direction. The problem I was having when I tried to create a custom report was that it's only possible to add filters with "AND" and not "OR". I was trying to add each page as its own filter parameter using AND which didn't work.

What ended up working was creating just one filter using a regex which matched all the different pages I wanted to include like this:

^/ppc-ase-1/$|^/cotf-thank-you/$|^/rt-sis-1/$

The | symbol functions as an "OR" in this regex so it includes all the pages.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to use custom reports in Google Analytics.

First, we have to prep the URLs. To add them together we have to use regex. In between each URL add a pipe "|" and around all of it add parentheses "()". If you have more than 5 URLs use this chrome extension - [URL Regex Generator](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/url-regex-generator/mdkhfhhdmebjkdnlcigpfhgdehkoikip). It will automate the process.

When finished, the URLs will look like this:

```
(/ppc-ase-1/|/cotf-thank-you/|/rt-sis-1/)
```

Second, in GA go to Behavior → Site Content → All Pages. Then open up the filters and click "advanced". Keep the settings as is and change "containing" to "Matching RegExp". Lastly add the URLs from the first step and boom.